# Install mmdebstrap from source

Tags: debootstrap, source-code

I am trying to install `mmdebstrap` from source. I cannot find any instructions online nor file any `Makefile`s and such in the [repo](https://gitlab.mister-muffin.de/josch/mmdebstrap)

Answer (score 0):

1. this seems to be a rather small project. If anyone on here knows it, it'd be by luck! So, often such repositories would come with references to mailing list, chat rooms or bug trackers. I'm not a fan of people asking *questions* on *bug* trackers, but lack of installation instructions is imho a bug, which one would want to track on such, and if you formulate it as bug report, instead of a unpaid support request, that'd be fine :)
2. Since this is inherently tied to the debian ecosystem, looking at the [official package](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/mmdebstrap), and how that is built, is going to get you further. Downloading `mmdebstrap_VERSION.debian.tar.xz` from that page, and looking at the `rules` file inside reveals:

```bash
    mkdir -p debian/tmp/usr/bin
    cp -a mmdebstrap debian/tmp/usr/bin/mmdebstrap
    cp -a taridshift debian/tmp/usr/bin/mmtaridshift
    cp -a tarfilter debian/tmp/usr/bin/mmtarfilter
    mkdir -p debian/tmp/usr/lib/apt/solvers
    cp -a proxysolver debian/tmp/usr/lib/apt/solvers/mmdebstrap-dump-solution
    mkdir -p debian/tmp/usr/share/mmdebstrap
    cp -a hooks debian/tmp/usr/share/mmdebstrap
```

Just remove the `debian/tmp` prefix, and there you go: here's how you install mmdebstrap from source.